# Akka.Net test Child actor creation/supervision with TestKit

Tags: c#, akka.net

I have Akka.Net code similar to the following and I am trying to write tests for it:

```
public class DoesSomethingActor : UntypedActor
{
    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {

    }
}

public class ForwardsMessagesActor : UntypedActor
{
    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {
        var actor = Context.ActorOf(Context.DI().Props<DoesSomethingActor>(), "DoesSomethingWorker");

        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            actor.Tell(message + " " + i);
        }
    }
}
```

I have got this test working but I am clearly missing something since I am not using much of TestKit at all. Is there still no official documentation for how to test this using TestKit ?

```
//creating actor mocks with Moq seems to confuse Akka - it just doesn't work 
//but creating mock classes manually like this, 
//then configuring them in the DI container works
public class DoesSomethingActorSpy : DoesSomethingActor
{
    public static List<object> ReceivedMessages = new List<object>();

    protected override void OnReceive(object message)
    {
        ReceivedMessages.Add(message);
    }
}

    [TestMethod]
    public void ForwardsMessagesActor_Creates5Messages()
    {
        //set up DI container to use DoesSomethingActorSpy as a child actor
        ContainerBuilder builder = new ContainerBuilder();
        builder.RegisterType<ForwardsMessagesActor>();
        builder.RegisterType<DoesSomethingActorSpy>().As<DoesSomethingActor>();
        IContainer container = builder.Build();

        var propsResolver = new AutoFacDependencyResolver(container, Sys);

        var actor = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<ForwardsMessagesActor>(propsResolver.Create<ForwardsMessagesActor>());

        actor.Tell("Test");

        //this looks wrong, I probably should be using something from TestKit
        Thread.Sleep(10);

        CollectionAssert.AreEquivalent(
            new[] { "Test 0", "Test 1", "Test 2", "Test 3", "Test 4" },
            DoesSomethingActorSpy.ReceivedMessages);
    }
```

How should I create mock actors? Is there any method on TestKit I can call to wait until all messages have been processed?

Comment: Could you explain your intentions here? It's not clear what are you trying to achieve. 

Concerning TestKit - there are API docs on official Akka.NET site. You can also get some introduction into TestKit from H. Canber blogposts [[1](http://blog.canberger.se/2014/10/introducing-testkit-for-akkanet.html)], [[2](http://blog.canberger.se/2014/10/integration-testing-using-akkanets.html)]. Finally on the akka.net github repository there are more than 1000 tests written in TestKit itself. It's good reference source.

Comment: @Horusiath I am trying to test the logic that creates child actors, and the error handling logic for those child actors. I have seen the H. Canber blogs, and a few others but they don't seem to deal with this scenario. Tests on akka.net github look promising though https://github.com/akkadotnet/akka.net/blob/dev/src/core/Akka.Tests/Routing/BroadcastSpec.cs

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoted from [How to Test Akka.NET Actors: Unit Testing w/ `Akka.TestKit`](https://petabridge.com/blog/how-to-unit-test-akkadotnet-actors-akka-testkit/):

> Testing the parent/child relationship is more complicated. This is one case where Akka.NET's commitment to providing simple abstractions makes testing harder.
>
> The simplest way to test this relationship is with messaging. For example, you can create a parent actor whose child messages another actor once it starts. Or you may have the parent forward a message to the child, and then the child can reply to the original sender, e.g.:
>
> ```
> public class ChildActor : ReceiveActor
> {
>     public ChildActor()
>     {
>         ReceiveAny(o => Sender.Tell("hello!"));
>     }
> }
>
> public class ParentActor : ReceiveActor
> {
>     public ParentActor()
>     {
>         var child = Context.ActorOf(Props.Create(() => new ChildActor()));
>         ReceiveAny(o => child.Forward(o));
>     }
> }
>
> [TestFixture]
> public class ParentGreeterSpecs : TestKit
> {
>     [Test]
>     public void Parent_should_create_child()
>     {
>         // verify child has been created by sending parent a message
>         // that is forwarded to child, and which child replies to sender with
>         var parentProps = Props.Create(() => new ParentActor());
>         var parent = ActorOfAsTestActorRef<ParentActor>(parentProps, TestActor);
>         parent.Tell("this should be forwarded to the child");
>         ExpectMsg("hello!");
>     }
> }
> ```
>
> #### A Word of Caution On Testing Parent/Child Relationships
>
> Avoid over-coupling your code to your hierarchy!
>
> Over-testing parent/child relationships can couple your tests to your hierarchy implementation. This increases the costs of refactoring your code later on by forcing many test rewrites. You need to strike a balance between verifying your intent and testing your implementation.